# What type of 3D object movement cannot be shown using transforms?

Tags: graphics, 3d

This is a question relating to 3D graphics. I thought maybe a non-uniform scale could not be shown in terms of transforms and matrix operations, but it can. I am looking for an example of a transform where this would not work.

Comment: We need way more context as to what you mean by a transform. Trivially any 1 to 1 change can be represented by a linear transformation.

Since in any nD space there's always a straight line between any 2 points. Non linearity only really exists for changes over time/paths

Comment: By transform I mean 3D transformations, i.e. scale, rotate, translate

Comment: Which are all, by definition, linear transformations